# Where do I find an icon of a mouse pointer?

Tags: wpf, icons

I want my WPF application to have a ToggleButton that contains an image of the mouse pointer in it.  The idea is that the user will choose one of three different cursors (the normal mouse cursor, the hand cursor, and a "zoom" cursor) by clicking on a ToggleButton.  I want the cursor image to show on the ToggleButton.

How do I get these icons onto my button?

Tony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are only three options, why don't you search for three images, and check the mouse around the, say, 30 secs and adjust the button, if needed.

Comment: so, google for the images, so you don't have to get them programmatically.

Comment: Yep, that's what I ended up doing.  Thanks